# simultaneously exec multiple shell_exec() commands?

Tags: php, process, command-line-interface, shell-exec

Hi so i am wondering if somebody can offer me a solution..

I have multiple instances of a php script i would like to run at once, I can semi achieve this using shell_exec() and not waiting for a response apart from the pid. This works wonderfully. However when doing this with the method below it works well for 100 or so executes but I need it to execute around 1000 times and it is taking too long to loop around the foreach and execute 1 by one.

Example:

```
 $items = $array(daatabase entries);

   foreach($items as $i){
    $pid = shell_exec("execute the process.php");
   }
```

Now assuming there are < 100 this will take around 1 second or so to exec which is OK however i need to run loads of these and this will take 10-20 seconds.

Is there any way of sending the commands in bulk rather than 1 at a time?

Thanks

Comment: do you expecting a response from your executed scripts ?

Comment: no I don't need the result - i already just get the pid back

Comment: how do you get the pid ? your php script ?

Comment: $pid = shell_exec("nohup nice -n 10 /usr/local/bin/php -c /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/etc/php.ini -f /home/USER/public_html/files/crons/test_process.php > /dev/null & echo $!")

Comment: well, you are sending your commands to background , so this is weird that iterating over 1000 rows takes all that time.

Comment: I am on a pretty basic VPS at the moment - moving to a dedicated server when i have built most of my application. Maybe this is the problem after further inspection I was actually hitting the max memory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like pthreads perhaps?

https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/
(The most recent result I could find)

Comment: Not looked at pthreads yet, I have heard this is an option though

Comment: I don't believe it's core PHP but seems to be well established. The only alternative I've tried was to call an endpoint which carries out the action using curl with a short timeout. Exactly like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874707/run-multiple-curls-in-background-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `process.php` in background without waiting for execution completion. So it will be faster. Also `shell_exec()` function returns only output, not `pid`. If you need `pid` you have to use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

```
   $items = $array(daatabase entries);
   foreach($items as $i){
      shell_exec("execute the process.php > /dev/null 2>&1");
   }
```